# Перевод из одной системы счисления в другую Java

Tags: java, char, системы-счисления

Требуется написать программу для перевода числа из X системы счисления в Y (2-16). Нельзя использовать `BigInteger` и сторонние библиотеки для перевода. Сделал только от (2-10) и наоборот. Вопрос вот в чем: как перевести из 16-ой ,скажем в 10-ю? Ведь в 16-ой системе используются буквы.

**Начал рассуждать так:**

Есть массив букв:

```
public char[] arr = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
```

**Далее идет перебор (NumStrText - получаемое на вход число):**

```
    char [] NumStrTxt = txtBoxNum.getText().toCharArray ();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < NumStrTxt.length; j++){
                    if(arr[i] == NumStrTxt[j]){
                        String constNum = i + 10 + "";
                        NumStrTxt[j] = constNum.charAt(i);
                    }
            }
     }
```

Логика такова: хотелось бы положить в массив `NumStrTxt`(Char) 2 элемента при обнаружении сходства с массивом букв(`arr`).Но проблема в том что `charAt()` берет только один элемент, а мне надо 2 так как Строка `constNum` реализует соответствие цифре A-10 B-11 и.т.д. Возможно есть другие решения задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть шестнадцатеричное число записано в строку. Зная длину строки, можно проходя её посимвольно слева направо умножать численное значение символа на соответствующую степень основания системы счисления. Можно реализовать с помощью switch по символу. Конечно, этот подход работает и для перевода из других с.с. в десятичную.